# cocos2d best practices, multithreading vs scheduler

Tags: multithreading, performance, cocos2d-iphone, scheduler

Well, there isn't much example code for this. I'm writing a game loop and I'm running into a snag. At first I attempted to create a schedule for the loop as this was listed under best practices as the way it should be done. My frame rate is 60 fps, and the loop was also running at an interval of 60 fps. I quickly noticed however that the interval time is little more than a suggestion, and the actual rate that the function is updating is highly erratic, ranging between 15 and 65 fps. This led to jumps in objects updating, even when their update distance was regulated as a function of time. Once updating dropped below 20 fps it became highly apparent when it updated and was quite ugly.

I then tried to create my own thread so that I could more closely regulate the update rate. With this method I was able to almost precisely regulate my updating rate. With this all movement and animations were smooth. The issue with this method is that cocos2d clearly doesn't support multithreading well as I periodically see screen tearing. Also, if my update rate doesn't precisely match my draw rate I see jumps. I believe this is due to the draw method firing in in the middle of my update loop, a common problem with multithreading.

The two ways I can think of to solve this problem are to find some way to closely regulate the firing rate of the scheduler, or to find a way to lock the drawing code until I can finish my update. I've been looking for quite some time for any examples on how to do either of these, and have met with no success. If anyone out there has a clearer idea of how to handle this kind of a situation I would be very appreciative of some advice. I'm just too used to C++ and having things happen at the rate I tell them to. If you need me to post any additional information, just ask! Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in your scheduled function. It just can't run as fast as you want. Try running helloWorld scene from cocos2d and you will notice that fps are stable near 60 (59.8 - 60.2)

Comment: It doesn't matter what rate I ask the scheduler to run at, even as low as 20 fps, it's still highly unstable. I'm not sure what cocos2d uses to manage it's refresh, as I suppose I could use the same method